# Generar excel en C

Tags: c, excel, eclipse, c++98

Buenas,

Estoy intentando crear una libreria para generar ficheros excel(.xls) en C,pero no tengo ni idea de como sacar hojas, aqui el codigo:

```
#ifndef SACAEXCEL_H_
#define SACAEXCEL_H_

//cada celda ira separada por una '\t' de la siguiente y por un \n si    queremos cambiar de linea
escribirLibro(nombreLibro,datos);
escribirRegistro(nombreLibro,nombreHoja,datos);

escribirLibro(nombreLibro,datos){
    FILE *pf;
    pf =fopen(nombreLibro,"w");
    fprintf(pf,datos);
    fclose(pf);
}
escribirRegistro(nombreLibro,nombreHoja,datos){
**Aqui el problema**
}
#endif /* SACAEXCEL_H_ */
```

Comment: Excel tiene un formato de archivo muy complejo, que ni siquiera Libreoffice ha sido capaz de implementar al 100%. ¿Seguro que quieres generar archivos Xls? Es mucho más fácil generar archivos CSV y luego importarlos en Excel

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta,si, podría sacar CSVs también, lo que me gustaría saber es si hay alguna forma de generar hojas o algún manual para sacarlos desde C.

Comment: Puedes probar usando la libreria [libxlsxwriter](https://libxlsxwriter.github.io/index.html)